# How to solve the problem with settings.json in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I was setting up my VSCode to auto format my code when I save changes but it took me to this settings page and told me I couldn't set it up before correcting these errors(as you can see in the picture). Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: don't you read the error messages in the PROBLEMS panel

Answer (score 0):

Provide property value for "/bin/bash":

[image]

Comment: i actually reset the vscode to default settings and the problem solved itself, thanks for your answers anyway.